# Shortcut For Number Theory Problem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer greater than or equal to $3$. Let $a,b$ be integers such that $ab$ is invertible modulo $n$ and $(ab)^{-1}\equiv 2\pmod n$. Given $a+b$ is invertible, what is the remainder when $(a+b)^{-1}(a^{-1}+b^{-1})$ is divided by $n$?

---

Is there a faster way or a short cut to do this problem rather than doing all the calculations directly?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $a^{-1}+b^{-1}=(a+b)(ab)^{-1}$